# Why X11 is not accepting my virtual mouse event?

Tags: xorg, mouse

I `float`ed my mouse in `xinput` and followed the instructions [here](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput) trying to inject mouse event.

I'm trying to read events from the mouse, change event code from `REL_Y` to `REL_WHEEL` and from `REL_X` to `REL_HWHEEL`, and inject the event back so that I can use the mouse as a 2d scroll wheel.

I think I got most of it working because when I run my program I see `event13` is added to `/dev/input`.
And in `dmesg` I do get :

```
input: uinput-sample as /devices/virtual/input/input28
```

And if I run `evtest /dev/input/event13` I get:

```
[linux-devkit]:/dev/input> sudo evtest event13

Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x1234 product 0xfedc version 0x1
Input device name: "uinput-sample"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 2 (EV_REL)
    Event code 6 (REL_HWHEEL)
    Event code 8 (REL_WHEEL)
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1457290441.973961, type 2 (EV_REL), code 6 (REL_HWHEEL), value 1
Event: time 1457290441.973961, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1457290441.981947, type 2 (EV_REL), code 6 (REL_HWHEEL), value 4
Event: time 1457290441.981947, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1457290441.989947, type 2 (EV_REL), code 6 (REL_HWHEEL), value 12
Event: time 1457290441.989947, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value 3
Event: time 1457290441.989947, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1457290441.997981, type 2 (EV_REL), code 6 (REL_HWHEEL), value 15
Event: time 1457290441.997981, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value 5
Event: time 1457290441.997981, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1457290442.005927, type 2 (EV_REL), code 6 (REL_HWHEEL), value 18
Event: time 1457290442.005927, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value 5
Event: time 1457290442.005927, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1457290442.013904, type 2 (EV_REL), code 6 (REL_HWHEEL), value 23
Event: time 1457290442.013904, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value 9
Event: time 1457290442.013904, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

But if I run `xinput list` I didn't see the virtual input device. And ubuntu is not responding to the event either.

What did I miss?

Do I need to create a slave device for it and attach it in `xinput`?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-uinput/+bug/1271310), `BTN_LEFT` and `BTN_RIGHT` must be set or xinput would not accept uinput virtual device as pointer slave.

After doing:

```
ret = ioctl(uinputFD, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_LEFT);
ret = ioctl(uinputFD, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_RIGHT);
```

the virtual device shows up in xinput and functions well.

So even if the virtual device only implements a subset of the function of a mouse, like only two wheel in my case, `BTN_LEFT` and `BTN_RIGHT` flags still need to be set.

Comment: Wow, it's 6 years later and this bug still isn't fixed yet! Even the kernel's mouse `uinput` documentation isn't accurate (https://docs.kernel.org/input/uinput.html), and I happened to stumble upon this deep into my search. Thank you so much.